# Regex using Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to catch from pattern that was downloaded from specific URL, specific values but without success.
Part of the pattern is:

```
"<a href="/wiki/All_My_Loving" title="All My Loving">All My Loving</a>"</td>\n<td style="text-align:center;">1963</td>\n<td><i>UK: <a href="/wiki/With_the_Beatles" title="With the Beatles">With the Beatles</a><br />\nUS: <a href="/wiki/Meet_The_Beatles!" class="mw-redirect" title="Meet The Beatles!">Meet The Beatles!</a></i></td>\n<td>McCartney</td>\n<td>McCartney</td>\n<td style="text-align:center;">\xe2\x80\x94</td>\n<td style="text-align:center;"><span style="display:none" class="sortkey">7001450000000000000\xe2\x99\xa0</span>45</td>\n<td></td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td>"<a href="/wiki/All_Things_Must_Pass_(song)" title="All Things Must Pass (song)">All Things Must Pass</a>"</td>\n<td style="text-align:center;">1969</td>\n<td><i><a href="/wiki/Anthology_3" title="Anthology 3">Anthology 3</a></i></td>\n<td>Harrison</td>\n<td>Harrison</td>\n<td style="text-align:center;">\xe2\x80\x94</td>\n<td style="text-align:center;">\xe2\x80\x94</td>\n<td></td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td>"<a href="/wiki/All_Together_Now_(The_Beatles_song)" class="mw-redirect" title="All Together Now (The Beatles song)">All Together Now</a>"</td>\n<td style="text-align:center;">1967</td>\n<td><i><a href="/wiki/Yellow_Submarine_(album)" title="Yellow Submarine (album)">Yellow Submarine</a></i></td>\n<td>McCartney, with Lennon</td>\n<td>McCartney, with Lennon</td>\n<td style="text-align:center;">\xe2\x80\x94</td>\n<td style="text-align:center;">\xe2\x80\x94</td>\n<td></td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td>"
```

I want to catch the Title and the 1st `<td>McCartney</td>` with specific values from the file and to print it out as a JSON file.

Can I run with FOR loop with regex ? How I can do it using python ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

If you want to parse HTML use an HTML parser (such as [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)), not regex.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<a href="/wiki/All_My_Loving" title="All My Loving">All My Loving</a>"</td>\n<td style="text-align:center;">1963</td>\n<td><i>UK: <a href="/wiki/With_the_Beatles" title="With the Beatles">With the Beatles</a><br />\nUS: <a href="/wiki/Meet_The_Beatles!" class="mw-redirect" title="Meet The Beatles!">Meet The Beatles!</a></i></td>\n<td>McCartney</td>\n<td>McCartney</td>\n<td style="text-align:center;">\xe2\x80\x94</td>\n<td style="text-align:center;"><span style="display:none" class="sortkey">7001450000000000000\xe2\x99\xa0</span>45</td>\n<td></td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td>"<a href="/wiki/All_Things_Must_Pass_(song)" title="All Things Must Pass (song)">All Things Must Pass</a>"</td>\n<td style="text-align:center;">1969</td>\n<td><i><a href="/wiki/Anthology_3" title="Anthology 3">Anthology 3</a></i></td>\n<td>Harrison</td>\n<td>Harrison</td>\n<td style="text-align:center;">\xe2\x80\x94</td>\n<td style="text-align:center;">\xe2\x80\x94</td>\n<td></td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td>"<a href="/wiki/All_Together_Now_(The_Beatles_song)" class="mw-redirect" title="All Together Now (The Beatles song)">All Together Now</a>"</td>\n<td style="text-align:center;">1967</td>\n<td><i><a href="/wiki/Yellow_Submarine_(album)" title="Yellow Submarine (album)">Yellow Submarine</a></i></td>\n<td>McCartney, with Lennon</td>\n<td>McCartney, with Lennon</td>\n<td style="text-align:center;">\xe2\x80\x94</td>\n<td style="text-align:center;">\xe2\x80\x94</td>\n<td></td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
a = soup.find('a')  # will only find the first <a> tag
print(a.attrs['title'])

tds = soup.find_all('td')  # will find all <td> tags
for td in tds:
    if 'McCartney' in td.text:
        print(td)

#  All My Loving
#  <td>McCartney</td>
#  <td>McCartney</td>
#  <td>McCartney, with Lennon</td>
#  <td>McCartney, with Lennon</td>
```

Comment: Hi, I used your answer in my code but I can't figure out how to continue with it.

Comment: Hi, I used your answer in my code but I don't know out how to continue with it.
The code I wrote is:
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_songs_recorded_by_the_Beatles"
request = urllib.request.Request(url)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
a = soup.find('a')  # will only find the first <a> tag
print(a.attrs['title'])
tds = soup.find_all('td')  # will find all <td> tags
for td in tds:
    if 'McCartney' and 'Lennon' in td.text:
        print(td)

Comment: 1. Continue in what sense? This code pretty much gathers all the data you asked for.  2. Wikipedia has an API that you should consider using instead of trying to parse the page itself. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page

Comment: I want to parse the HTML itself, I know about the the API of Wikipedia but I want to practice on parsing html.

Comment: Is their any option to it ?